# linked list program for polynomials exits without giving any output

Tags: c, function, linked-list, arguments, polynomials

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int coff;
    int pow;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head1 = NULL;
struct node* head2 = NULL;

void insert(int c, int p, struct node* head){
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* temp = head;
    newnode->coff = c;
    newnode->pow = p;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newnode;
    }else{
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newnode;
    }
    
}

void display(struct node* h){
    struct node* temp;
    temp = h;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%dx^%d ", temp->coff, temp->pow);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    
    insert(3,2,head1);
    insert(5,1,head1);
    insert(4,0,head1);

    insert(9,2,head2);
    insert(6,1,head2);
    insert(2,0,head2);

    display(head1);
    display(head2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I have created node struct for my linked list. Then i have created two functions for insert and display polynomials. I have created head1 and head2 for store address of two different polynominals. And I want use that head1 and head2 as arguments in insert and display functions. then finally I wanna print both polynomials. But there is a bottleneck. When I execute my program it exits without giving any output.

My expected output is :

3x^2  5x^1  2x^0

9x^2  6x^1  4x^0

How can i solve this problem? Is there anything wrong with (struct node* head) arguments in the functions? Why this program exits without giving any output?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think you mean 9x^2 5x^1 4x^0 for the second output

Comment: @AbhayAravinda Yes. It was my mistake. Sorry about that. I will edit that.

Comment: regarding: `struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" );` so both the error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`.

Answer (score 2):

Your line `head = newnode;` isn't actually changing `head1` and `head2` because the pointers themselves were passed by value. This results in `head1` and `head2` remaining `NULL`, and thus resulting in no output. You can fix this issue by passing a pointer to a pointer to the head node to `insert`. A quick modification to your code to implement this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int coff;
    int pow;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head1 = NULL;
struct node* head2 = NULL;

void insert(int c, int p, struct node **head){
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* temp = *head;
    newnode->coff = c;
    newnode->pow = p;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    
    if(*head == NULL){
        *head = newnode;
    }else{
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newnode;
    }
    
}

void display(struct node* h){
    struct node* temp;
    temp = h;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%dx^%d ", temp->coff, temp->pow);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    
    insert(3, 2, &head1);
    insert(5, 1, &head1);
    insert(4, 0, &head1);

    insert(9, 2, &head2);
    insert(6, 1, &head2);
    insert(2, 0, &head2);

    display(head1);
    display(head2);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at
`void insert(int c, int p, struct node* head)`

Because 'head' is passed by value (and all C parameters do so),
caller of this function has no chance to get the 'inside modified' `head`.
So, in your case, in `main()`, `head1` is always NULL.

I modified a bit from your code, it seems works:)
But don't forget to `free` all allocated nodes.

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int coff;
    int pow;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head1 = NULL;
struct node* head2 = NULL;

struct node* insert(int c, int p, struct node* head){
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    struct node* temp = head;
    newnode->coff = c;
    newnode->pow = p;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    
    if(head == NULL){
        head = newnode;
    }else{
        while(temp->next != NULL){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newnode;
    }
    
    return head;
}

void display(struct node* h){
    struct node* temp;
    temp = h;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%dx^%d ", temp->coff, temp->pow);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(){
    
    head1 = insert(3,2,head1);
    insert(5,1,head1);
    insert(4,0,head1);

    head2 = insert(9,2,head2);
    insert(6,1,head2);
    insert(2,0,head2);

    display(head1);
    display(head2);
    
    return 0;
}
```